# How to make circles stay circles and resize on different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uibutton

I really need help, I made an app I designed everything for iphone 7 I designed it with constraints and now I am having a problem because they don't look right on SE or 4s.

I am using circles made with IBDesignables(using cornerRadius to make circles). I want them when it resizes to stay circles because I tried couple of things and when it resizes its not a circle anymore.

Sorry for the long paragraph I just really need a tip !

How can I solve this problem

Here is how it looks on Iphone 7
[image: iphone 7]

Here is how it looks on Iphone SE
[image: SE]

Here is how it looks on Iphone 4s
[image: 4s]

Comment: What seems to be the problem? The circles are looking like circles only in all images.

Comment: making the height and width same for the views making the top view disappear from the top, try to implement aspect ratio to the views and set the rounded corners through code by getting the view height or width

Comment: Give me some time and i will give you an example through github repo

Comment: @SahebRoy as you can see on 2nd and 3rd pictures some views are being cut off , and about the circles yea they are circles but i said I Tried some things but they dont stay circles

Comment: @SubhajitHalder I would be thankful if you do that take your time and also I wanted to know how can I make the text size on the buttons to get smaller for different screen sizes??

Comment: Have to set height,width & spaces between two controls based on screen witdth & height.Use multiplier to adjust size for those circles

Comment: What are the constraints you are adding for the views. I'm not a magician to magically know your code so share your code that you are using to create the circles and top rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that all view stay circle for all device you must keep their height and width same.

You can easily do this thing with Autolayout set Aspect ratio of that view is 1 so their height and width remain same  check screen shot

[image]